# vertical wrap just like it works horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a div container (the light green one) with smaller divs inside (the blue ones) which I want to align as shown in the image.

[image]

Just like the default horizontal wrap works, but "rotated 90 degrees".

I was playing around with [CSS columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) with no success. I only want to define a fixed width for the columns and don't want to set a specified number of them. It should be dynamic and depend on the height of the container. I guess this code is pretty near:

```
div.container {
    column-width: some length;
    column-fill: auto;
}
```

and all I have to do is defining the column-count property in some way but I don't know how.

Or are there maybe better ways to do this than CSS columns?

Comment: Columns are not supported in browsers yet. http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We want our divs to be laid out in a column so we use `flex-direction: column;`.
- We don't want one single large column but allow wrapping so we use `flex-wrap: wrap;`.
- To group all our columns to the left we use `align-content: flex-start;`.
- We must avoid our div to grow unlimited, like height by default does, so we need to restrict the height somehow. The height is the space that remains in the container below the other div ⇒ `height: calc(100% - 10em);`.

Everything together in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/25byp248/).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use flexbox on your container if you have a fixed height for it. So the code would look something like this

```
div.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 500px; //Whatever height you want
}
```

@CBrow has posted a great link above, that's like a cheat sheet for flex box, read more on it and see what you can use

Answer (score 0):

Thanks VeeK and CBroe, I tried flexbox, but I cannot get it to work how I want it. This is the closest I can get:

```css
div.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 25em;
    height: 17.5em;
    background-color: #dfffbf;
}
div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #729fcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
</div>
```

The issues: 1. It shouldn't be justified horizontally. 2. It should work with a container that has dynamic height.

...So just like the normal horizontal flow that browsers normally do, just in a vertical manner.

Comment: Use `align-content: flex-start;` instead of `align-items` to get three narrow columns on the left. What should determine the height of the container?

Comment: Thanks, `align-content: flex-start;` solved the justification issue. I've extended the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swirlsky/jr41g2ey/1/) to show you how the container's height is determined. In my layout it also has a container (div1 in fiddle) the height of which is defined, and it should fill in the remaining space in it. So the items (the blue small divs) should expand it vertically until it fills up all the space in its container, and at that point when no more items fit in the first column, then comes the first break and the next item goes into the next column.

Comment: So if I don't give a height to container, for some reason it overflows div1. That's the last problem that has to be solved somehow. If you replace the line `/* height: should be 17.5em; */` by `height: 17.5em;` in the CSS, you can see how it should look like.

Comment: Yes, it _should_ be 17.5em. In this example that's clear; we can calculate the remaining height ourselves and add it as an extra rule. But I'm guessing you're looking for a dynamic solution? Something like `height: calc(100% - 10em);` for your div.container?

Comment: Any browser that already supports flexbox also supports calc, so it is the solution I guess. I think "what we did here" is already a good elaboration on this vertical wrap problem of mine, so if all your help would be in one single answer I could accept it.

Comment: Okay. Didn't you have another comment about forcing the wrapper to a 16:9 ratio?

Comment: I did, but later I decided to delete it as my situation is very unique, and after trying calc() I was surprised that it works perfectly in any modern browser even in my situation even though I'm manipulating the height by JS based on which it has to calculate. So yeah... You summed it up pretty well in your answer, and it works perfectly :)